# ¿Cómo hacer para que un botón de tkinter imprima un código ya creado con muchos print?

Tags: python, tkinter, botón, print

Buen día, estoy intentado agregar un código (con muchos **print**) que ya tengo creado a un botón en **tkinder**, y me imprima todo los **print** del código en una cuadro de texto en una ventana emergente.

Por lo pronto, esto es lo único que tengo:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

import contextlib
import io
import tkinter

ventana = tkinter.Tk()
ventana.geometry("400x300")

def embed():
    toplevel = tkinter.Toplevel(ventana)
    text = tkinter.Text(toplevel)
    text.pack(fill=tkinter.BOTH, expand=True)

    file = io.StringIO()
    with contextlib.redirect_stdout(file):
        algunos_prints()
        text.insert(tkinter.END, file.getvalue())

def algunos_prints():
    print("hola")
    print("desde")
    print("StackOverflow en Español")
    page3 = requests.get(urls3)
    soup3 = BeautifulSoup(page3.content, 'html.parser')
    urls3 = 'https://monoschinos.com/ver/gleipnir-episodio-7' #MONOSCHINOS
    episodio = soup3.find('h1',class_='Title-epi mt-4')
    print(episodio.get_text("text").rsplit(' ',3)[0]+(" - Episodio ")+(episodio.get_text("text").rsplit(' ',3)[1]))

boton = tkinter.Button(ventana, text="compila",command=embed)
boton.pack()
ventana.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No puedes  realizar un `print` con salida sobre un widget `tkinter.Text` de forma directa, debes insertar el texto mediante el método `tkinter.Text.insert`.

Para la ventana emergente usa siempre `tkinter.Toplevel`:

```
import tkinter


ventana = tkinter.Tk()
ventana.geometry("400x300")

def embed():
    toplevel = tkinter.Toplevel(ventana)
    text = tkinter.Text(toplevel)
    text.pack(fill=tkinter.BOTH, expand=True)
    text.insert(tkinter.END, "hola\n")
    text.insert(tkinter.END, "desde\n")
    text.insert(tkinter.END, "StackOverflow en Español\n")

boton = tkinter.Button(ventana, text="compila",command=embed)
boton.pack()
ventana.mainloop()
```

Aunque no de forma directa, si que realmente es posible redirigir los `prints` al widget `Text` mediante un buffer que haga de intermediario, por ejemplo:

```
import contextlib
import io
import tkinter


ventana = tkinter.Tk()
ventana.geometry("400x300")

def embed():
    toplevel = tkinter.Toplevel(ventana)
    text = tkinter.Text(toplevel)
    text.pack(fill=tkinter.BOTH, expand=True)

    file = io.StringIO()
    with contextlib.redirect_stdout(file):
        algunos_prints()
        text.insert(tkinter.END, file.getvalue())

def algunos_prints():
    print("hola")
    print("desde")
    print("StackOverflow en Español")

boton = tkinter.Button(ventana, text="compila",command=embed)
boton.pack()
ventana.mainloop()
```

Puede serte útil si quieres modificar los prints de una función y no quieres modificarla.

Comment: Gracias por responder, Estoy intentado imprimir un codigo que ya tengo creado, Edite mi pregunta con una parte ya agregada, Use tu ejemplo pero no me reconoce las variables. Edite mi pregunta, respóndeme de nuevo porfavor

Comment: Disculpe fue error mio, Su ejemplo me ha funcionado de maravilla, Muchas gracias!!.